# Align XML drawable background to bottom of view

Tags: android, android-view, drawable

I am trying to provide a simple solid-color underline to a TextView header. I want this to be reusable and to work with any view in the future, regardless of height. I am trying to favor a background drawable so I can simply apply it to view. I can draw a line without any problem:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:shape="line"
    >

     <stroke
        android:color="#8a9299"
        android:width="1dp"
        />

</shape>
```

This line is, however, centered in the background of the view. I see a bunch of online tutorials that use layers to draw a background-colored rectangle and then "peek" another rectangle from behind, however I don't know what background color this header element type will be used on, and transparent rectangle backgrounds show the color rectangle below. Is there any way to stick to a line but give it a bottom gravity inside the view it is applied to?

Comment: You could put a relitave layout (or liniear layout with vertical orientation) as parent of the element and the line you want to put with the element. Then align the line to the bottem of the element

Comment: As noted in the question, I'd like to contain the alignment information in the drawable itself or the view using it so it can be applied either directly or via a style in one line. I have traditionally done this using viewgroups like this, but I'm trying to find a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using gradientDrawable. Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:centerX="0.1" />
</shape>
```

Increase/Decrease `centerX` to increase/decrease width of your underline. Change `startColor` to change the color of the underline.

**Explanation**:

`angle` is the angle of the gradient. 0 is left to right. 90 is bottom to top.

`startColor` is the start color of the gradient. Our angle is 90 so the gradient starts from bottom (and so it appears like an underline)

`centerColor` is the centerColor which is transparent.

`centerX` is the X position of the gradient as a fraction of the width. Keep it small (<0.1) for a good looking underline. Anything above 0.1 looks bad (nobody is stopping you though!).

Comment: This is nice! Unfortunately, it starts to stretch on really tall views, but I like the dynamic nature that can easily be applied! It has some shortcomings, but it's very close to what I was hoping for and may be as close as Android will let me get…

Comment: if you are ok with thinner underline, change centerX to maybe 0.05 or even 0.01. This will reduce the stretching

Comment: I tired those, but in a quick test they chose not to render on shorter views. I'll do some more extensive testing when I get a chance!